# App Indexing: Is using App Indexing API necessary for publishing deeplinks, if it is already been provided access by Googlebot?

Tags: android, googlebot, android-app-indexing

I have implemented app indexing in my app, to redirect deeplinks from Google Search results to app and we are using "custom applink" for deeplinking.

I have included all the necessary coding in Android Manifest file, by following the Google Documentation for app indexing, https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app. Also confirmed from server team that all the links are provided access by Googlebot.

I am not using App Indexing API in the code for publishing deeplinks, as the links have access by Googlebot.

Can someone please point to me if am missing out something and guide on the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the App Indexing API, though it does make some things easier & it's Google's recommendation.

In this case, it does look like something's still not quite set up correctly, so I'd recommend verifying the app in Search Console [https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en], checking the app crawl errors there, and using Fetch as Google to double-check that Google can see the content appropriately.

If you can't get further with these steps, it would help to have the URI of the app & website.

Answer (score 0):

All Google App Indexing does is convert your website link into a link that will open your app when installed. Once you've added the metatag to your website and Google can scrape it, then you're done!

Here's an example metatag:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="myapp://path/to/thing"/>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, this is already part of the website link, but still it doesn't redirect to app. One more query is, if there is a mobile site for the content, should the metatag be part of that link as well or metatag in website link should be sufficient?

Comment: I work at Branch (https://branch.io) and we create deep links to do just this for apps. We've created probably close to a billion links at this point. Google never automatically opens the app in the search result even though we put these tags there. We have to do it with redirection and JS in the service unfortunately :( Their marketing videos make it look great but doesn't work in practice.